serverless run --debug has wrong framework & node version? (different from serverless.yml)
I'm trying out serverless run --debug to investigate another problem (here's my actual current error message) and noticed something odd - my serverless_framework version & node version don't seem to match my serverless.yml specification.
Here's some output from serverless run --debug:
s:cli: {
  node: 'v20.12.2',
  os: 'linux',
  arch: 'x64',
  shell: '/bin/bash',
  cwd: '/mnt/c/home/mtgpuzzles/puzzle-serverless',
  nodeJsPath: '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v20.12.2/bin/node',
  scriptPath: '/root/.serverless/releases/4.0.28/package/dist/sf-core.js',
  scriptArgs: [ 'run', '--debug'],
  logLevel: 'debug',
  isInteractive: true
}
s:cli: { serverless_framework: '4.0.28' }
s:core: {
  versions: { serverless_framework: '4.0.28' },
  command: [ 'run' ],
  options: { debug: 'puzzle-server' },
  configFileDirPath: '/mnt/c/home/mtgpuzzles/puzzle-serverless',
  customConfigFileName: null
}
s:main: Initializing
s:core:router: {
  command: [ 'run' ],
  options: { debug: 'puzzle-server' },
  versions: { serverless_framework: '4.0.28' },
  configFileDirPath: '/mnt/c/home/mtgpuzzles/puzzle-serverless',
  isWithinCompose: false,
  composeOrgName: null,
  composeServiceName: null
}

and the relevant parts from my serverless.yml file:
frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x

As you can see, I specify frameworkVersion: '3' in yml but the debug message says v4.0.28 & I specify nodejs18.x as runtime but cli says node 'v20.12.2' is being run.
Is my serverless.yml being ignored? Should I be running something other than just serverless run --debug in the same folder as my serverless.yml? Or am I just misinterpreting the serverless debug logs?
